# Bypass Google's tracking links

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

Google has an annoying practice of sometimes using tracking links, so when you click on a search result, you are first directed to a Google URL that silently gathers stats, then redirects you to the actual result.

Is there a simple way to disable/bypass this? I'm thinking some sort of Firefox plugin or Greasemonkey script - yes, I've looked. Logging out of my Google account is not really ideal either.

P.S. I have no problem with Google collecting data, but my work connection is extremely slow and this makes it twice as bad.

Comment: duckduckgo.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this [Google click-tracking disabler](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/24399)

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/121261) is better and newer version of it.

Also [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/serp-click-tracking-disab/dnclnjppifnecphigphjgmcfkdopokgm?hl=en) is available for Chrome but I like installing [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) and installing that linked userscript more because it doesn't use timer and implemented much better IMO.